# When cand I use "that is" or "to be"?

Tags: grammar, american-english, informal-language

I am from Mexico, so English is not my first language. I'd like to know when can I say "that is" or "to be" because in Spanish is the same

For instance:

I want a room that is big in Spanish: Quiero una habitación que sea grande

I want you to be more intelligent: Quiero que seas mas inteligente

as you can se "to be" and "that is" means = "que sea"

when can I use "that is" and when "to be"

Comment: One distinction between English and Spanish usage is that *that* is not used to express wishes.  It (the word _that_) can be used to indicate a specific object out of many options.  Ex.: _My bike is the one that has a flat tire._

Comment: No, I don't think that's correct at all.   "I want a world that is peaceful and green."   Perfectly good use.

Answer (score 1):

In Spanish, the preposition 'que' can function as many different words in English:  "that", "which", "what", and so forth.

Likewise, in English, some words function as many different words in Spanish, depending on context: "that" by itself can be like "que", "para que", or even "quanto" depending on the context.

In the example you give, the difference is that in

> I want a room that is big

you are not talking about an actual room that is there before you, it's hypothetical or you are imagining it.   Sort of like:  "If I could make a new room..."

But in the case of

> I want you to be more intelligent

the actual person you want to be more intelligent is right there with you.   It's not imaginary or hypothetical, you only get one.   Sort of like:  "If I could change *this particular one*..."

```
I want my room to be bigger.
```

^ This means you want to keep the same room you have and make it bigger.

```
I want a room that is bigger.
```

^ This means you want to get a new room that is larger than the one you have.

This isn't always the rule with "that is" and "to be", though!   It's just one way that it can work; there are other ways of using both.